# Using express and consolidation.js how do I then add locals to my render?

Tags: node.js, express

had to add consolidate.js due to some routes being raw HTML and others being pug. but all this did work when i was only using pug as the view engine.

on Index.js

```
const cons = require("consolidate");
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.engine('pug', cons.pug);
```

from what i've found the on from the readme of consolidate.js this is what I ended up with:
on a route.render(get) request:

```
    const message = `Please enter a valid word.`;
    const noResults = { message };
    return res.render("wtd_index.pug", { 
      title: "wtd_index", 
      noResults: noResults });
```

the page loads but i can't get the locals to come through. or any of the information that is dynamic.

i feel like it's a simple fix but can't figure it out from the readme/online communities. and if it helps i used the consolidate to go from just pug to pug and html.

I've also tried naming it the same name as the title since the consolidate example i was viewing was a little tricky using the 'users'.

```
return res.render("wtd_index.pug", { title: "wtd_index", wtd_index: noResults });
```

Comment: What result did you get? Is there any error? Provide the debugging details

Comment: @LinDu so the results would be my page would render, there was no errors, but all the information that came out of the local variables wouldn't be there. But i figured it out. was just the Key:value naming in the render object.